# Define Result Fields if blank then another field

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

What I'm trying to do is, if a field is blank, use another field within `WRKQRY`(Query/400) in define result fields. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an SQL view using the `RUNSQLSTM` command and then run a query over the view.

```
CREATE VIEW QTEMP/MYVIEW AS
SELECT F1, CASE WHEN F2 <> ' ' THEN F2 ELSE F3 END AS FX FROM MYLIB/MYFILE
```

Then tie it all together with a `CL` program.

```
PGM

DLTF FILE(QTEMP/MYVIEW)
MONMSG MSGID(CPF0000)
RUNSQLSTM SRCFILE(MYLIB/MYSRC) MBR(MYMBR)
RUNQRY QRY(MYLIB/MYQRY)

ENDPGM
```

Comment: why would you want to delete and re-create the view every time the query is run?

Comment: @WarrenT It's just a personal preference.  I don't like to leave seldom-used objects permanently on the system.

Comment: Ok, as long as it is understood that there is no overhead with having a view over a table, since it is not maintaining a keyed access path.  In the example code you are deleting the view from last time, then re-creating it for this run, but the code does not delete it.  And in an attempt to reduce extra infrequently used objects, you have created an extra CL *pgm which will be infrequently used. Just sayin. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Query/400 is obsolete, and should be considered deprecated.  It was replaced about 2 decades ago by Query Management.  Query/400 queries run under the old database optimizer (CQE) and cannot benefit from newer faster optimization techniques employed by the new optimizer (SQE).  It is recommended to migrate Query/400 queries to QM Query or to DB2 Web Query.

Fortunately, Query Management Queries can be created in a prompted mode which should be very familiar to Query/400 users.  Prompted-mode queries can be converted to the more powerful SQL-mode.

You can use the `RTVQMQRY` command to generate SQL source from the Query/400 query you have asked about  Once you have the source, you can then use the `CASE ... END` expression given by @Mike.  Create the QM query with the `CRTQMQRY` command, and run it with `STRQMQRY`.

Comment: Also, if the SQL product is on the system, QM is there at no extra cost. But Query/400 **is** extra cost and provides fewer features and less flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need to do this, I can show you how to do it in 3 passes of Query 400.
Yeah, I know that's not efficient but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Take a [look](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/db2/rbafzmst151.htm) at `CASE` that should work for you.

```
CASE field
    WHEN ' ' THEN newfield
    ELSE field
END as myfield
```

Comment: im not sure if this is what im looking for its not a DB2 SQL statement its for QUERY 400

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you can in `WRKQRY`. You might need to use SQL to do what you want.